# Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sql-server-2008-r2

Has anybody encountered this error?

I added the TCP port 1433 to the inbound firewall rules, also I made sure that the named pipes are enabled. But still, I cannot connect to SQL Server (2008 R2).

I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, error:2)

Comment: Is it enabled on the SQL Server instance?